# Installling sonatype nexus as a service in Windows

Tags: windows, service, nexus, sonatype

Just to inform other people who had the same problem.
When installing sonatype nexus OSS 3.6 on windows as a service using

```
>.\nexus /install
```

I got the following error message:

```
Could not open SCManager
```

Comment: You can install with running Command Prompt using Administrator priviliges. But can you start with same, currently I am facing error: "Windows could not start the Service1 service on a local computer"

Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: To install it as a service. Open command prompt with admin rights and change directory to the folder in which nexus.exe is present.  E.g : In mine case E:\Nexus\nexus-3.24.0-02\bin.   Type >>  nexus.exe install in command prompt and hit enter.  Browse to  http://localhost:8081/ and you will get welcome page of nexus

Answer (score 2):

Run windows Command Prompt using [Administrator privileges](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/).